# Unable to ES6 import ChartJS plugin into Aurelia

Tags: chart.js, aurelia

I'm using `chart.js` in my Aurelia application and it works fine.

I now want to add the `chartjs-plugin-deferred` plugin as well, and after having `npm install`:ed it and added it to `aurelia.json`'s `dependencies` array I now get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined`

Pointing to the first couple of lines in the plugin code:

```
var Chart = window.Chart;
var helpers = Chart.helpers;
```

(Note that I don't even need to *use* the plugin (`import 'chartjs-plugin-deferred';` for the error to appear; as soon as it's added to aurelia.json I get errors).

If I add a `console.dir(window.Chart)` before the lines that throw errors it is in fact *not* undefined, and if I try to use the plugin in my charts it actually works fine.

Can someone explain why this error occurs and if there's some way I can get rid of it? I feel uncomfortable shipping code that, while it works as it should, throws errors in the console.

I'm a huge fan of npm and imports etc but more often than not you run into issues such as these which imo is such a hassle and actually makes me miss the good old days of just piling `script` elements on top of each other.

Edit: I tried with a couple more plugins just to see if perhaps the `deferred` plugin was the issue here, but every other plugin I tried completely kills the build.

Does anyone have experience importing ChartJS *and* a ChartJS plugin into Aurelia successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue at hand is that the library does not provide any meaningful way to jump in with a module loader and properly first fully load the dependency ChartJS before carrying on with the execution.

It would be the best if the library could wrap its code in a UMD compatible format to satisfy the most common formats at once, amongst those RequireJS, which is used for the Aurelia CLI.

I see you've created a [Github Issue](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-deferred/issues/2), including the libraries author as well. Good work, I've created a small PR to add the missing feature, which then also makes the example work, without throwing the missing helper error.

Comment: Thanks man :) https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-deferred/issues/2